# Почему файл сохраняется не до конца(обрезается конец)?

Tags: java, filewriter

Есть строка `String` длиной в 64 тысячи символов. Когда вывожу ее на экран, то строка получается целиком.

Когда пытаюсь сохранить ее в файл за раз, обрезается до 49151.

```
System.out.println(string);
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file, false);
writer.write(string);
```

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

После завершения записи надо закрывать поток вывода:

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file, false);
writer.write(string);
writer.close();
```

Начиная с Java 7 еще можно делать так:

```
try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file, false);)
{
   // code
}
```

все классы, созданные в скобках блока `try`, которые реализуют интерфейс `AutoClosable` при выходе из данного блока/исключении автоматически закроются посредством вызова метода `close()`

Answer (score 1):

Не обязательно закрывать поток, мало ли он вам ещё понадобиться. Тогда можно выполнить:

```
writer.flush();
```

чтобы записать все данные из буфера в файл и продолжить работ с потоком. И всё же нужно не забыть закрыть поток по завершении работы с ним.